# SilverStripe change page type icon

Tags: php, silverstripe

How do you change the page type icon (aka sitetree icon) for a certain page type, using the default icons in the framework?

Example: the form page icon.

[image]

**edit**
I want to use one of the icons within the sprite file: `sitetree_ss_pageclass_icons_default.png`

Comment: `static $icon = "mysite/images/icons/foobar.png";` ...and adapt path to where ever. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Well that would probably work, but I want to use one of the default icons in `sitetree_ss_pageclass_icons_default.png`. This is a sprite file that holds multiple icons.

Comment: That is not possible without writing your own CSS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If someone stumbles over this one and has the same question... yes you can.

define what ever image-file

```
static $icon = "mysite/images/icons/foobar.png";
```

If the image is a sprite you can add CSS as needed

```
LeftAndMain:
  extra_requirements_css:
    - mysite/style/fixCMSstyle.css
```